# Has anyone gotten the Liferay portal to deploy onto an Eclipse Virgo Web Server?

Tags: liferay, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to deploy the Liferay portal onto the Eclipse Virgo Web Server and haven't had much luck.  I have at least solved two of the problems involved in this process:

1) The portal.jar that is part of the liferay dependencies has a malformed manifest.  The Bundle-SymbolicName incorrectly sets the value to "JSR 286" when it should be "JSR286" (no space).  Also, the Import-Package has a bunch of spaces/tabs and I removed those.  That took care of problem 1.

2) The Virgo web server wasn't finding the liferay dependency jars (at least not where I was putting them), so I just stuck the dependencies into the main liferay.WAR and that has gotten rid of all the error messages.

Unfortunately, this didn't solve the overall problem.  Perhaps there are other issues, but Virgo is not reporting any errors.

I've looked on both the Liferay and Virgo forums, but no one seems to have an answer to this, so I'm hoping someone here has had more success than me.  If so, please let me know what you tried to get it to work.

A little more detail: I used the liferay-portal-6.0.5 WAR that is *not* bundled with an app server.  And, I'm using Virgo 2.1.0.

Thanks,

David

Comment: This question looks like it will get answered by technological evolution...http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-13704?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

I got it! http://sourceforge.net/projects/liferayforvirgo. But Virgo 3.6.0.RELEASE demonstrates too low performance and the couple Liferay+Virgo is not able to use for production